# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property 'innerText' on string '

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom

I'm trying to dynamically add posts to my post div, and I'm getting an error when trying to add image urls. I tried changing it from innerText to innerHTML and had the same issue. It's also not showing the array I added.

```
// creating DOM variables 
let button = document.getElementById("btn");
let postForm = document.getElementById("post-form");
let displayPostsCont = document.querySelector(".displayPosts");
let title = document.getElementById("postTitle");
let author = document.getElementById("authorName");
let text = document.getElementById("textP");
let image = document.getElementById("newPostImageUrl");

//when a new post is added, it'll be pushed into this array
const posts = [{
  title: "My first blog post",
  author: "Kam",
  text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Sagittis id consectetur purus ut faucibus pulvinar elementum integer enim. Pretium aenean pharetra magna ac placerat vestibulum lectus.",
  image: "https://images.pexels.com/photos/936048/pexels-photo-936048.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1"
  },
  {
  title: "My second blog post",
  author: "Kam",
  text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Sagittis id consectetur purus ut faucibus pulvinar elementum integer enim. Pretium aenean pharetra magna ac placerat vestibulum lectus.",
  image: "https://images.pexels.com/photos/936048/pexels-photo-936048.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1"
  }
];

const addPost = (title, author, text, image) => {

}


//  Create the the blog post with elements, then append it

const createBlogPostElement = ({title, author, text, image}) => {
  //create elements
  const postDiv = document.createElement('div');
  const blogPostTitle = document.createElement('h2');
  const authorName = document.createElement('h6');
  const authorPost = document.createElement('p');
  const authorImg = document.createElement('img').src = "";

  // add in content
  blogPostTitle.innerText = "Blog post title: " + title;
  authorName.innerText = "Author name: " + author;
  authorPost.innerText = "post: " + text;
  authorImg.innerText = "image: " + image;

  // add  to the DOM
  postDiv.append(blogPostTitle, authorName, authorPost, authorImg);
  displayPostsCont.appendChild(postDiv);
}

posts.forEach(createBlogPostElement);
```

Answer (score 1):

This statement is suspect in two ways:

```
const authorImg = document.createElement('img').src = "";
```

1. `authorImg` will be the result of the assignment (the string being assigned), not a reference to the `img` element.
2. If it *were* a reference to the `img` element, [`img`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) elements can't have *content*, they can just have image itself and alt text. That means you can't set their `innerText` (or `innerHTML`, or append elements to them, etc.).

You probably wanted:

```
const authorImg = document.createElement("img");
authorImg.src = image;
```

(And then remove the `authorImg.innerText = "image: " + image;` statement later.)

You might also do:

```
authorImg.setAttribute("alt", "an appropriate description of the image for accessibility");
```

```js
// creating DOM variables
let button = document.getElementById("btn");
let postForm = document.getElementById("post-form");
let displayPostsCont = document.querySelector(".displayPosts");
let title = document.getElementById("postTitle");
let author = document.getElementById("authorName");
let text = document.getElementById("textP");
let image = document.getElementById("newPostImageUrl");

//when a new post is added, it'll be pushed into this array
const posts = [
    {
        title: "My first blog post",
        author: "Kam",
        text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Sagittis id consectetur purus ut faucibus pulvinar elementum integer enim. Pretium aenean pharetra magna ac placerat vestibulum lectus.",
        image: "https://images.pexels.com/photos/936048/pexels-photo-936048.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1",
    },
    {
        title: "My second blog post",
        author: "Kam",
        text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Sagittis id consectetur purus ut faucibus pulvinar elementum integer enim. Pretium aenean pharetra magna ac placerat vestibulum lectus.",
        image: "https://images.pexels.com/photos/936048/pexels-photo-936048.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1",
    },
];

const addPost = (title, author, text, image) => {};

//  Create the the blog post with elements, then append it

const createBlogPostElement = ({ title, author, text, image }) => {
    //create elements
    const postDiv = document.createElement("div");
    const blogPostTitle = document.createElement("h2");
    const authorName = document.createElement("h6");
    const authorPost = document.createElement("p");
    const authorImg = document.createElement("img");
    authorImg.src = image;

    // add in content
    blogPostTitle.innerText = "Blog post title: " + title;
    authorName.innerText = "Author name: " + author;
    authorPost.innerText = "post: " + text;

    // add  to the DOM
    postDiv.append(blogPostTitle, authorName, authorPost, authorImg);
    displayPostsCont.appendChild(postDiv);
};

posts.forEach(createBlogPostElement);
```

```html
<div class="displayPosts"></div>
```

Comment: I figured it out what was missing, it had to do with the link address. Thank you!